# Allow ip addresses dynamically using .htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache

Before asking my question, I would like to state that I do not  have knowledge in apache server, therefore I do not know if it is feasible what I am going to ask.

On my server there is a folder named admin. At the moment its access is restricted only to 3 ip_addresses  using .htaccess as shown below:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now I would like to ask you if it is possible to add/update the ip_addresses dynamically using php and include the php created file in the .htaccess.

For example

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ip_one" />
<input type="text" name="ip_two" />
<input type="text" name="ip_three" />
</form>
```

file.php

```
<?php
$ip_one = $_POST['ip_one'];
$ip_two = $_POST['ip_two'];
$ip_three = $_POST['ip_three'];

//AND THEN REPLACE THE EXISTING IP ADDRESSES IN THE .HTACCESS WITH THE THRE VALUES ABOVE


?>
```

Undoubtedly this is not the way to reach what I would like to obtain. Is there a way to manage the ip_addressess dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically do it via some kind of script. An idea might be to make some sort of page you have to authenticate to in order to run. The script would grab your ip, and insert it into the .htaccess file.

Although if you were going to do that, you could just remove the ip restriction and instead implement a password authentication scheme, since that's basically what it is at that point.

Comment: Hi Elshar, thanks for your answer. I have no idea how to pass the ip address in the .htaccess file using php. Do you have an example or a link which explains how to proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most important drawback of this all, is that you need the PHP user (that's your web user) to have sufficient rights to write in your .htaccess file. Normally that's not allowed or otherwise the web user could compromise that.

I can imagine running a crontab to do this.

You let PHP create a dummy .htaccess.php and whenever crontab runs, it picks up that .htaccess.php file and moves it to .htaccess. Since crontab has more rights than your php (aka web user) - this should work.

Still - make sure that your php script can not create a .htaccess that allows for people to do more than you want.